# std::find on a legacy array

Tags: c++, stl

How can i conduct `std::find` on a legacy array **without making a new `std::vector`/`std::array` from an existing legacy array**?

for example:

```
int ar[N];

if ( std::find(ar, ar + N, value) != &ar[N] ){ /**/ }
```

Is `&ar[N]` a valid value for checking the situation when nothing is found? Can I be sure i'm doing right using `&ar[N]` like an analog of `std::vector::end()` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using c++11, you can use:

```
int arr[N];
if (std::end(arr) == std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), value))
{
    // ...
}
```

For c++98, you can use:

```
int arr[N];
int *begin = arr;
int *end = begin + N;

if (end == std::find(begin, end, value))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's not hard to write your own version of `std::begin` and `std::end` either.

Comment: to add to marks comment, also boost provides begin and end too.

Comment: Is there any advantage of the C++11 version over the C++98 version?

Comment: If I would go for a reverse_iterator I would need to end on a (begin - 1)?

Answer (score 4):

Your general idea is good. But `ar[N]` is not "reserved" for you. Dereferencing a not allocated variable will lead to undefined behavior. Your want to compare `std::find` result with `ar + N`, which does not involve dereferencing.

Comment: Your first sentence is "Your solution is good." but then you say it's actually not good. Which one is it?

Comment: Checking for the adress of ar[N] is indeed a good solution. But, he needs to not dereference it. Sorry if I didnt made myself clear.

Comment: You're saying "your solution is good". His solution involves `&ar[N]`, which is clearly not good. Also "Derefenrencing a not allocated variable could lead to undefined behavior." implies that there are situations where it wouldn't lead to UB, which again is wrong.

Comment: I corrected my sentence to more absolute statement about the result of dereferencing `ar[n]`. What I mean with "Your solution is good" is that his idea was good, only the implementation implied runtime errors.

Comment: I edited your answer. (I didn't downvote though, so it's not up to me to remove the downvote)

Comment: Thank you for the comments and edit. My English is not perfect yet, and people telling me where I'm not making myself clear helps me get better everyday :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure dereferencing `ar[N]` is well-defined if it's for the sole purpose of taking its address (which is what's happening here).

Answer (score 3):

> Is &ar[N] a valid value for checking the situation when nothing is found?

You can use `ar+N` instead of `&ar[N]`, because `ar +N` is safe but `&ar[N]` falls into the region of undefined behavior (there is a long debate over that in fact).

Semantically speaking, the second argument is *actually* **end** of the range, so whatever you pass as second argument is returned when *nothing* is found in the range. In your case, `ar + N` is the second argument, which also indicates *end* of the range. So you can write this:

```
if ( std::find(ar, ar + N, value) != (ar + N) )
{ 
       //value found
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `&ar[N]` is legal? Doesn't it involve dereferencing?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That is a long debate but the usual conclusion is in favor.

Comment: There's special language for pointers allowing the address of the element past the end to be meaningful.  There's no such special behavior enabled for references, `ar[N]` produces undefined behavior in any evaluated context, including `&ar[N]`.

Answer (score 2):

No, `ar[N]` dereferences one element after the end of the array, so it's illegal.

Remember that `ar[N]` is equivalent to `*(ar + N)` - so it's clearly a dereference.

Go with `ar + N` instead. It's legal to have a pointer 1 following the end of an array, it's illegal to dereference it.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use `std::begin` or `std::end()`.

```
int ar[N];

if ( std::find(ar, ar + N, value) != ar+N ){ /**/ }
```